# Is there a name for this theorem: if the angle between two vectors goes to zero, then all norms give the vectors the same ordering?

Tags: limits, terminology, normed-spaces, order-theory, alternative-proof

Assume we have:

- two vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $\Vert u \Vert > \Vert v \Vert$, with $\Vert\Vert$ being the euclidean norm
- $f$ a norm (not necessarily a norm, we only need positive definiteness and absolute homogeneity)
- $\theta$ the angle between $u$ and $v$

Proof:
\begin{equation}
A=f( u) -f( v)
\end{equation}

let $e_{i}$ ,$e_{j}$ be basis vectors such that:

\begin{align}
e_{i} \cdot e_{j} &=0\\
u&=\Vert u\Vert e_{i}\\
v&=e_{i}\Vert v\Vert \cos( \theta ) +e_{j}\Vert v\Vert \sin( \theta )\\
\end{align}

then:

\begin{align}
A&=f( e_{i}\Vert u\Vert ) -f( e_{i}\Vert v\Vert \cos( \theta ) +e_{j}\Vert v\Vert \sin( \theta ))\\
&=f( e_{i})\Vert u\Vert -f( e_{i}\cos( \theta ) +e_{j}\sin( \theta ))\Vert v\Vert
\end{align}
thus:
\begin{align}
\lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0} f( e_{i})\Vert u\Vert -f( e_{i}\cos( \theta ) +e_{j}\sin( \theta ))\Vert v\Vert =f( e_{i})(\Vert u\Vert -\Vert v\Vert ) \geqslant 0
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0}f(u)-f(v) \ge 0
\end{equation}
So $f(u) \ge f(v)$ for a sufficiently small angle $\theta$.

I would like to know if such proof already exists so I can cite it in a paper.
I'm also wondering if there are studies on the relation between the ordering given by the norm and the angle for specific norms, or for norms with additional constraints.

Comment: Please show whatever you have done. Don't skip your proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited my question to add the proof.

Comment: You may want to use the tag [terminology].

Comment: @soupless thanks, it is done.